# Disable compression for Nginx serving PDFs

Tags: nginx, compression

How do I disable compression for PDFs using Nginx? Related question, how do I stop Adobe Reader from automatically opening the PDF, instead of saving it to the hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, nginx enables gzip only for text/html by default so there is no compression when serving PDFs 
You can setup types you want to gzip (remember that for text/html is on always) by:

> gzip_types text/css text/js text/xml;

Second is client side. I can't possibly think a way other then to told user to right-click and save to...

Answer (score 4):

On the second part, you just have to set the Content-Disposition header to supply a preferred filename and the browser will display a save-file dialog.

I don't know how you would cause Nginx to do that, in php I just use this code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wootwoot.pdf"');
```

Be sure to use this BEFORE php outputs any data…

Comment: nginx has add_header directive ( http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule#add_header ).  
You can place it under `location ~ \.pdf$`